# combine two arrays in php in unique case

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following 2 arrays variable.

```
$a = array("triple","triple","double","single","single");
$b = array("444","555","33","2","3");
```

i need to convert that 2 arrays to be this array pattern

```
$array = array(
    "triple"=>array("444","555"),
    "double"=>array("33"),
    "single"=>array("2","3")
);
```

so that i can get the result like this

`triple(444 | 555) double(33) single(2 | 3)`

anyone can help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `array_combine`, `$b` as keys and `$a` as values, then transfer to a new container grouping them with the key:

```
$array = array();
foreach(array_combine($b, $a) as $k => $v) {
    $array[$v][] = $k;
}
```

For presentation purposes, just `implode` them:

```
foreach($array as $key => $numbers) {
    $href = implode('|', $numbers);
    $numbers = $key . '(' . implode(' | ', $numbers) . ')' . ' ';
    echo "<a href='aaa.php?numbers=$href'>$numbers</a>";
}
```

Comment: i want to ask, how can i add link to `$numbers` in implode? like `<a href="aaa.php?numbers=$numbers">$numbers</a>`

Comment: @WilliamChandra just assign it inside a variable

Comment: @WilliamChandra its already on the edit

Answer (score 0):

You Can use PHP's Array_unique ... [Follow this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

And do the following..

```
$arr = [];
foreach($a as $value) {

 if ( $value == 'tripple' ) {
   foreach( $b as $val ) if( strlen($val) == 3 ) $arr[$value][] = $val;
 }

if ( $value == 'double' ) {
   foreach( $b as $val ) if( strlen($val) == 2 ) $arr[$value][] = $val;
 }

if ( $value == 'single' ) {
   foreach( $b as $val ) if( strlen($val) == 1 ) $arr[$value][] = $val;
 }

}
```

That should work...

Comment: i know how to use `array_unique`, the question is how to show the result as i expected when i unique the first array?

Comment: Check above.. I have updated my Answer..